# how to pass 2 return types in a method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm in a service method that is supposed to return a user list, but in case it doesn't return this list it is supposed to return a string. I did some research it seems that I have to use a generic  the problem is that I have trouble to understand how it works and therefore adapt the synthax to my use case. Thanks for your help.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Utilisateur>> AllUtilisateur(FormUserDTO formUserDTO)
{
 if(user){
   return user //Is a list
 }
 return error // Is a string
}
```

Comment: You need to type the result as a common type. A typical trick is to type it as an interface that both/all possible result types implement. Ultimately all types inherit from `object`, but that usually makes for a very bad choice. Why can't you instead throw an exception for that error?

Comment: Why would you want to _return_ the error? How about _throwing_ it?

Comment: Well you could change your method to return a `Task<object>`... but it would usually be better to use exceptions for error handling. If you can't do that, consider creating a result type that contains properties for both the error and the success results (but where any one instance will only have a non-null value for one of them).

Comment: You *could* use a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), but as other's pointed out, I'd highly suggest throwing an exception

Comment: To answer it from a pure return type point of view, this pattern is typically called the "Either" pattern I believe. I don't necessarily recommend doing this but you can read more about it here: https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/either-data-type-alternative-throwing-exceptions, and you can find other sources as well.

Comment: @Sweeper indeed you are right it will be easier and cleaner, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try a small wrapper class that encapsulate the result you want

```
public class AsyncTaskResult<T>
{
    public string Error {get; set;}
    public T Value {get; set;}
    public bool Failed => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);
}


public async Task<AsyncTaskResult<IEnumerable<Utilisateur>>> AllUtilisateur(FormUserDTO formUserDTO)
{
 if(user){
   return new AsyncTaskResult<IEnumerable<Utilisateur>>> { Value = user } //Is a list
 }
 return new AsyncTaskResult<IEnumerable<Utilisateur>>> { Error = error } // Is a string
}
```